# How to keep the typing on callback function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

`foo` function returns an object. typescript is know about the typing that return `prop1` and `prop2` wrap in promise:

```
const foo: ({ a, b }: {
    a: any;
    b: any;
}) => Promise<{
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
}>
```

But when I wrap `foo` function with `fn` function, then `b` variable that create by the callback is losing the typing and become `const b: (a?: any, b?: any, c?: any) => Promise<any>`.

My question is how to fix that so typescript can know about the typing? what I try to get is `b` variable will be the typeof the function I pass. in this case is `foo` function.
Like that:

```
const b: Promise<{
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
}>
```

I try to use `T`: `const fn = <T>(cb: T) => {` but it throw an error on the callback and not sure what is mean. I don't know if I correct about this.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-man2bk?file=index.ts)

```
const foo = async ({ a, b }) => {
  console.log({ a, b });

  return {
    prop1: 'prop1',
    prop2: 'prop2',
  };
};

const fn = (cb) => {
  return async (a = null, b = null, c = null) => {
    const results = cb({ a, b });
    if (results) {
      return c();
    }
  };
};

const bar = () => fn(foo);

const b = bar(); // const b: (a?: any, b?: any, c?: any) => Promise<any>
```

Comment: Well, `fn(foo)` *does* return `async (a = null, b = null, c = null) => {…}`, so I don't see what's wrong with the type `(a?: any, b?: any, c?: any) => Promise<any>`.

Comment: "*I try to get the `b` variable to have the type of the function I pass*" - but that's just wrong. A `fn`-wrapped function doesn't return the same as the passed function, it returns either nothing or `c()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you question correctly you can do something like this

```
const fn = <T>(cb: ({a, b}: any) => Promise<T>) => {
  return async (a = null, b = null, c:() => T | null = null) => {
    const results =  cb({ a, b });
    if (results) {
      return c();
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: `fn` is still have typescript of `Promise<any>`. I try to have typing of `Promise<{ prop1, prop2 }>`

Comment: @JonSud but you are returning `c()` that  is not defined as a type. try to return result instead

Comment: @JonSud I edited my response but be aware that `c()` defined like that can cause some problem